# You frequently use me on the net. What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I am a six letter word.

My **1,2,3** is very abundant on earth.
My **2,3,4** is an organ.
My **3,4,5** is part of circle

You frequently use me on the net.
***What am I?***

Comment: Why is the answer in the comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **SEARCH**

Most abundant on earth:

> sea

An organ:

> ear

Part of a circle:

> arc

You frequently use it over the net:

> search

Comment: oops, I was 1 minute too late :(

Answer (score 5):

I would say it's

> SEARCH

Taken further next three is part of circle

> ARC

Taken next three together is an organ

> *AR can only be EAR

Taken first three together is most abundant on earth.

> *EA I guess it's SEA

So it gives us

> SEARCH

Comment: Made changes in the question.